# Распознавание голоса в приложении

Tags: java, android, распознавание-речи

Программа при распознавании голоса, выводит на экран массив похожих слов. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы выводился не массив слов,а именно сказанное слово? Если да, то как?

```
emailText = findViewById(R.id.email_text);
private static final int Print_Words = 100;
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Вызываем RecognizerIntent для голосового ввода и преобразования голоса в текст:
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Скажите слово для распознавания");
            startActivityForResult(intent, Print_Words);
        }
    });
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    //Проверяем успешность получения обратного ответа:
    if (requestCode == Print_Words && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Как результат получаем строковый массив слов, похожих на произнесенное:
        ArrayList<String> result=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //и отображаем их в элементе TextView:
        assert result != null;
        emailText.setText(result.toString());
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как это массив, то мы просто выводим его первый (в массиве нулевой) результат, потому что на первом (нулевом) месте стоит самый, похожий на сказанный, результат.
`emailText.setText(result.get(0));`